# can't create a structure for png in C

Tags: c, struct, png

I can't figure out what's wrong with my structure.

Here is a really rudimentary structure for nested **PNG** head's data :

```
typedef struct _chunk Chunk;
typedef struct _file_header file_header;


#pragma pack(push, 1)

struct _chunk
{
    unsigned int size;
    unsigned char type[4];
};

struct _file_header
{
    unsigned char signature[8];
    Chunk ihdr;
};

#pragma pack(pop)
```

here's a snippet of the main program :

```
int main ()
{
    FILE* img;
    file_header* h;

    if ((img=fopen("flower.png", "rb")) == NULL) {
        printf("file not found.\n");
        exit(1);
    }


    h = (file_header*)malloc(sizeof(file_header));
    fread(h, sizeof(char), sizeof(file_header), img);

    // the ouput from the printf below should be "13"
    // but what it shows is "218103808" !! (?)
    printf("%i\n", h->ihdr.size);

    free(h);
    fclose(img);
    return 0;
}
```

Could someone explain to me what is wrong with this structure, or if nothing's wrong what should I change to make things working out ?

Comment: Just my 2 cents, but reading files into `struct`s is a really bad idea IMHO, regardless of packing the structure or not. You've got to battle things like endianess and the like. Better read into a apropriately sized buffer and extract the single fields from there.

Answer (score 3):

Byte order.

You have read the bytes `00 00 00 0D` from the disk and stuffed them straight into a low-endian integer, where they're interpreted as 0 + 256*0 + 65536*0 + 16777216*13 = 218103808

What you probably should do is to convert integers from big-endian to machine format after fread-ing the data. Or write utility functions to read relevant data from a file pointer (or file descriptor) and write a dedicated "load a PNG function" that calls the individual data-type-specific readers and populates your struct(s).